# tomcat 5.5 not showing manually deployed applications

Tags: java, deployment, war, tomcat5.5

I have installed tomcat 5.5 server on my debian machine,
I tried to deploy my first HelloWord applicaiton on it. when i deployed it manager dashboard shows me Ok message in message box but, in application list it is not showing me my newly deployed application.
I found that my application is present in tomcat5.5/webapps folder. 
I tried to access application using URl like localhost:8081/helloWord, it is showing me 404 error page.
Can any one tell what went wrong with my server.

Comment: why 8081? The default port of Tomcat is 8080. Have you tried with that port ?

Comment: check ur capitalisation, port no...

Comment: i have manually changed the port to 8081, and there is no any type. also i am running tomcat on Debian server, not on windows

Answer (score -1):

Use latest version of tomcat or if windows is pirated change it... Sometime it happens due to pirated windows. this may fix your problem

Have fun

Comment: i am not using windows its debian server